# Share alsa capture device with alsaloop

Tags: configuration, audio, alsa

I'm trying to 'share' the microphone input such that programs can have access to it.

---

Initial naive attempt.

In one terminal:

```
alsaloop -C hw:1,0 -P hw:0,0 -t 500 -c1 -A 5 -T-1 --resample -v
```

In another terminal:

```
$ arecord -D hw:1,0 -d 5 -f S16_LE > silence.wav
arecord: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Reference:

```
hw:1,0 - microphone input
hw:0,0 - output
```

---

I think the following is what I need: http://alsa.opensrc.org/Dsnoop

But I'm unsure how to properly configure my `.asoundrc`.

I tried the following:

```
pcm.dsnooped {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        channels 1
        rate 48000
    }
}

pcm.foo {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dsnooped" # use our new PCM here
```

The following would work:

`arecord -D foo -d 5 -f S16_LE > recording.wav`

And am able to play it back: `aplay recording.wav`

But then `alsaloop` doesn't seem to recognize `foo`:

```
alsaloop -C foo -P hw:0,0 -t 500 -c1 -A 5 -T-1 --resample -v
```

In fact this seems to hang and I have to kill it with `pkill -9 alsaloop`

---

Does anyone have some ideas or suggestions on how to make this work?